# Multiple components in a cms-element configComponent?

Tags: vuejs2, shopware, shopware6

I have tried to place a `sw-colorpicker` in my `configComponent`, but it's not showing up.

Already tried:

```js
{% block sw_cms_element_test_config %}
  <sw-media-field v-model="imageId" required validation="required" />
  <sw-colorpicker value="#fff" :alpha="true" v-model="imageTextBackgroundColor" label="pick a damn color ffs!" />
{% endblock %}
```

When I add another component, it simply does not show up. Only the first is showing. E.g. In this case the `sw-media-field`.

I also tried placing each component in it's own block, as I have seen done in other code, but that also was not working. If I change the order of the components, then `sw-colorpicker` will show, but not the other one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the root of the template there should only be a single element. To wrap multiple children, you may use a generic component like `sw-container` for example.

```html
<sw-container>
    <sw-media-field v-model="imageId" required validation="required" />
    <sw-colorpicker value="#fff" :alpha="true" v-model="imageTextBackgroundColor" />
</sw-container>
```